# Xamarin forms zxing scanner in android showing blank camera, unable to scan barcode

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

[image]

Xamarin.Forms `ZXing` scanner in Android is showing blank camera. I am unable to scan a barcode. Please find the image.

My Code

```cs
var scan = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
var result = await scan.Scan();
HandleScanResult(result);
```

Comment: Did you added permisions on android project, for camera?

Comment: Yes permission is given iin the android manifiest  for both flash and camera..Am able to open the camera it is  showing Scanning line but unable to scan the barcode..

Comment: I had attached the screenshot for reference